# IIS stopped serving static content over a certain (small) size

Tags: iis, iis-10, static-content

I'm really hoping somebody can help apply some sanity to this IIS issue that has been driving me crazy. I seem to be experiencing the same problem as the poor soul in this thread: https://forums.iis.net/t/1240175.aspx.

**NOTE: I posted this earlier today on Superuser - I realized there is a large base of IIS-tagged questions on SO so thought I'd also post here.**

**OS:**
Windows 10 Pro 64-bit 2004 19041.508

**Problem:**
Basically, IIS will not serve static content over a certain arbitrary size - static files over that size will just timeout eventually. Non-static content, for example asp files do not have this limit and load as expected regardless of size. This started happening seemingly out of nowhere with no directly related IIS/system/network/permission changes.

**Things I've Tried:**

- Yes, static content is turned on!
- Same thing, every browser
- Completely virus/malware free
- Disabled ad blocker/anti-virus/firewall/etc.
- No proxies (except when Fiddler is running)
- Completely removed IIS (disabled feature, moved \inetpub and \windows\system32\inetsrv) and re-enabled feature which recreated them)
- Checked logs, enabled tracing
- SFC scan clean
- Checked permissions, toggled app user between IUSR and domain user

**Details:**

About a 1 or 1.5 months ago my local IIS stopped working, out of the blue. By out of the blue I mean the the previous day it was working fine as always and the next it stopped - without having done any system changes whatsoever. By stopped working I mean (eventually realized) that it was only static files that were not serving correctly. Unfortunately/fortunately, I noticed the problem because I had created the obligatory personal COVID tracker. It was html/js running against a .NET API back end. The pages stopped loading and I spent time wondering what I had borked in the code (which I also hadn't touched).
Eventually I realized no static content - images, css, js, html, txt etc. - was loading properly. I ran some tests and I found that there was a cutoff point in size of content that would load, but it is somewhat arbitrary. For example, the iisstart.png image in the default IIS website does not load - it's 97K. I replaced it with an 8k file that loads fine. I could get about 1500 bytes served in an html file - 1501 bytes would send it off the rails but 1500 worked. Same sort of thing was found for text files although I was able to send more than 1500 bytes - don't remember how much but did find a point where a 1 byte difference caused a problem.

**Test Load of Default IIS Website:**

IIS log is not helpful - it reports the failed attempt as a 200 but says it took 19 seconds. It **is** returning a **win32 status code of 121** though:

```
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2020-10-23 13:36:12 127.0.0.1 GET /iisstart.png - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+rv:82.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/82.0 http://localhost/ 200 0 121 18944
```

The tracing mostly doesn't fire I guess because the 200 is eventually returned?

Fiddler gives me this for the image request:

```
[Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a complete response for this request. Server returned 0 bytes.
```

For this site the actual html loads fine - it's only 696 bytes - the image it references does not though (97K).

If anybody can shed some light on this or give me a direction in troubleshooting I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Is static content compression enabled?

Comment: 1500 bytes is interesting - because that's also the default MTU for Ethernet (though file-size plus HTTP headers would exceed this... ) - how's your physical network?

Comment: `win32-status == 121` means there was a timeout (possibly disk IO timeout - or network timeout - or something). I wonder if you have a failing disk. Check your hardware event-log.

Comment: @Dai, I tried with static compression on/off and otherwise my network and disk are fine. I thought the  same thing and did a disk scan and smart check etc. No other symptoms except this.

Comment: Nothing in the event logs

Comment: Most IIS questions should go to IIS.net forums or ServerFault.com. There are IIS posts here only if programming related. Enable FRT and you should easily get more hints on why 19 seconds is taken by a simple image, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis I doubt that you installed something on IIS or Windows that injects into the process.